# Open links in another window with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, window.open

Let's say I have a single HTML page and it contains hundreds of links. These links will load in the same window when anybody clicks them.

I want it to open in another window. I know that I can use `target` for each link:

```
<a href="http://www.example1.com/" target="_blank">My Text1</a>
<a href="http://www.example2.com/" target="_blank">My Text2</a>
<a href="http://www.example3.com/" target="_blank">My Text3</a>
```

Howeder, I'd prefer to use JavaScript if that's possible. Is it possible to do that with JavaScript, and if so, how?

Comment: Yeah, you can add target="_blank" with javascript.

Comment: A google search of your question title would have gotten you the same answers as below.

Comment: Exactly, I don't get how these answers aren't found before asking ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Use something like this:

```
var newtab = window.open('http://www.example1.com/', '_blank');

newtab.focus();
```

This may open in new tabs or new windows depending on the particular browser, but I don't know of a way to control that any more specifically.

**EDIT**
Or were you asking for a way to set the behavior for all links on the page? Then you can add the proper target to all of them when the page loads.

With jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/b8hdv/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

...or without jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/uFvUS/

```
window.onload = function(e) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].target = '_blank';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, for all links on the page..i have tried your codes,but it doesn't work..could you check it again please ? thanks

Comment: If there is no "target" for my current links `<a href="http://www.example1.com/">My Text1</a>` ..can this work for me?

Comment: @user2203703 you'll need to run the script when the page is done loading (if you're not already). I edited my solution to include the wrapper functions; see if that works.

Comment: @user2203703 sorry, I forgot to close the function. Also you should use jsfiddle's dropdown stuff on the left to import libraries (see the examples I added). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
function open_in_new_tab(url )
{
  var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

Use like this:

```
$("#a_id").on("click", function(){
open_in_new_tab($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

**Demo HTML:**

```
<a href="somepage.html" id="a_id">Click me!</a>
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.open('http://www.example1.com');
```

and capture the event click.